# UNION ALL error Unknown column order by

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Buenas tengo la siguiente query

```
SELECT d.fechaSeguimiento ,d.horaInicio ,d.horaTermino ,d.HH ,d.HM, d.Comentario,m.NroSolicitud,
d.Int_Prod,s.reparacion, p.Nombre ,p.Codigo,m.maquina FROM MAN_SeguimientoDetalle AS d
        LEFT JOIN MAN_TecnicoSeguimiento AS t ON t.id_detalle = d.id_detalle
        LEFT JOIN personal AS p ON p.Codigo = t.id_tecnico
        LEFT JOIN MAN_Seguimiento AS s ON s.idMan_Tecnico = d.id_man_tecnico
        LEFT JOIN MAN_Solicitud AS m ON m.NroSolicitud = s.NroSolicitud
        WHERE t.id_tecnico IN ('397') AND d.fechaSeguimiento BETWEEN  '2020-05-01' AND '2020-05-11' 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ma.fecha, ma.TotalHrs ='' as horaInicio, ma.TotalHrs ='' as horaTermino ,ma.TotalHrs as HH, ma.TotalHrs as HM, ma.Comentario,
ma.NroSolicitud ,ma.TotalHrs = 'No' as Int_prod ,ma.orden ='' as reparacion ,ppp.Nombre ,ppp.Nombre, a.DescArea FROM MAN_Actividades as ma
   LEFT JOIN personal AS ppp ON ppp.Codigo = ma.id_tecnico 
   LEFT JOIN area as a ON a.CodArea = ppp.Area 
 WHERE ma.id_tecnico IN ('397') AND ma.fecha BETWEEN  '2020-05-01' AND '2020-05-11'
 ORDER BY t.id_tecnico,ma.id_tecnico ASC, m.NroSolicitud,ma.NroSolicitud DESC, d.fechaSeguimiento,ma.fecha DESC
```

Pero si deseo ordenar by el `ORDER BY` tengo el siguiente error `SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: Unknown column 't.id_tecnico' in 'order clause'`
Pero si le quito el order by funciona bien, pero sin poder ordenar.

Adjunto una foto del la query sin `ORDER BY`
[image: FOTO DE LA QUERY FUNCIONANDO SIN ORDER BY]

Comment: Quítale esa `t.` del `id_tecnico`, con suerte no te dará ambigüedad y evitas depurar la consulta entera buscando qué alias asignaste

Comment: @DavidJP me tira el siguiente error `Unknown column 'id_tecnico' in 'order clause'`

Comment: Qué curioso, debería darte al menos ambigüedad, pues tienes otro campo idéntico como `m.id_tecnico`. Incluye en la pregunta el dataset para probar la consulta a ver qué puede ser (phpMyAdmin, Exportar)

Comment: @DavidJP Entendi ya el tema, no habia declaro esa variable en el select!

Comment: Prueba agregar el `t.id_tecnico` al `select`